# Simply creating a data structure, how can it segfault?

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, malloc

i have a simple program on data structure but it segfaults and it frustrates me so much because i have absolutely no idea why. can anybody point out anything about this code (even not relevent)? thanks

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct prof
{  
    struct prof *next;
    char c;
    int x;
    int y;
} profile;

profile *create_profile(char c, int i, int j)
{
    profile *new_elem;
    new_elem = (profile*)malloc(sizeof(profile));
    if (new_elem == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    new_elem->next = NULL;
    new_elem->c = c;
    new_elem->x = i;
    new_elem->y = j;
    return (new_elem);
}

int main()
{
    profile **king = NULL;
    *king = create_profile('K', 1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*`return (new_elem);`*": No need to put the argument to `return` in to parenthesis. `return` is *not*  a function.

Comment: the code is written according to the norm in my school. i learned that and then it feels better to go beyond the norm.

Comment: Well, your use of `return` is not consistent.

Comment: Show your teacher that you can ask smart questions and ask him/her why to put the parentheses around `return`s argument ... ;-)

Comment: there is no teacher. but the norm is the ultimate. a file has max 5 func, a func inputs max 5 parameters, inside the func i can create max 5 var, every var has to be initialised.. other silly stuff when i look back, but it helps initially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your king is a pointer to a pointer to struct.
You need some place to store the pointer to struct in, but that is what you do not allocate.
You can introduce a pointer in order fix this.

```
int main()
{
    /* introduce and NULL-init a pointer to struct */
    profile* prince = NULL;
    /* actually the init to NULL is not necessary,
       because prince gets initialised later indirectly via king
       (credits to alk), but it does not hurt and initialising everything
       is a good habit. */ 

    /* Introduce a pointer to pointer to struct,
       initialised with the address of above pointer to struct,
       the address of the above variable "prince" to be precise and clear.
       The space for that automatic local variable is not dynamic,
       it does not require a malloc. */
    profile **king = &prince;

    /* what the king is pointing to, i.e. the prince,
       gets assigned what the function returns,
       which is a cleanly allocated pointer to a new struct. */
    *king = create_profile('K', 1, 1);

    /* if king were still NULL, above statement would try to write
       (the cleanly allocated pointer) into memory by dereferencing NULL ... 
       segfault! 
       (Well not necessarily, as alk points out, credits.
       But dereferencing NULL is undefibed behaviour,  
       an almost guaranteed way to trouble in the long run
       and in case a seggault is observed, a likely explanation.
     */ 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Like the `prince`  ... :-) Still, setting it to `NULL` is not necessary to make this work.

Comment: @alk True. Will add a comment. Thanks for the explicit input and the implicit one I picked up from a different answer.

Comment: why you dont need to use malloc here?

Comment: @linchi: Because defining a variable also allocates memory.

Comment: You need to use malloc to make space dynamically. If the space is already there, in the shape of a variable (prince), there is no need.

Comment: @alk I feel like having been accompanied by you across the 10k border (even if you did not upvote). Thanks buddy.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Congratulations! :-) I did UV, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
profile **king = NULL;
*king = ...
```

dereferences `NULL`, which by itself already invokes undefined behaviour. On top of this the code then tries to write there. Not good, as `NULL` does not point to valid memory.

Answer (score 2):

You have to allocate memory first to `profile **king` and then allocate memory to `*king`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct prof
{  
    struct prof *next;
    char c;
    int x;
    int y;
} profile;

profile *create_profile(char c, int i, int j)
{
    profile *new_elem;
    new_elem = (profile*)malloc(sizeof(profile));
    if (new_elem == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    new_elem->next = NULL;
    new_elem->c = c;
    new_elem->x = i;
    new_elem->y = j;
    return (new_elem);
}

int main()
{
    profile **king = (profile**) malloc(sizeof(profile*)); // <-- see here
    *king = create_profile('K', 1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those casts are useless. `malloc()` returns `void*`. C implicitly converts a `void`-pointer to any other pointer type.

Comment: Yes @alk, it may be useless, but it shouldn't affect during runtime. If I am right, casts are mostly done during compile time.

Comment: yes, i need `**king` to be a pointer to pointer so that it holds `*king`. then king needs to hold a pointer to `profile` structure

Comment: @linchi, I guessed that! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The code segfaults at

```
*king = create_profile('K', 1, 1);
```

Because you've defined `king` to

```
profile **king = NULL;
```

Meaning that king is now a pointer to a pointer. But `king` doesn't actually point anywhere, you say that it points to `NULL`. Dereferencing a pointer pointing to `NULL` will cause a segfault.

If you instead define `king` as

```
profile * king = NULL;
```

And assign it like

```
king = create_profile('K', 1, 1);
```

The code should no longer segfault.

Comment: "*Dereferencing a pointer pointing to NULL will cause a segfault*" not necessarily. Still, it *will* invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused in using double pointer. Try using like this

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct prof
{
    struct prof *next;
    char c;
    int x;
    int y;
} profile;

profile *create_profile(profile *head,char c, int i, int j)
{
    profile *new_elem;
    new_elem = (profile*)malloc(sizeof(profile));
    if (new_elem == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    new_elem->next = head;
    new_elem->c = c;
    new_elem->x = i;
    new_elem->y = j;
    return (new_elem);
}

int main()
{
    profile *king = NULL;
    king = create_profile(king,'K', 1, 1);
    return 0;
}
```